# How to tell if an exectuable (in any format) is compressed

Tags: compression, executable

My question is, are there any tools out there that can detect what compression tool was used to compress an exeutable?

It doesn't matter what executable format the executableis in.([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Executable_file_formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aExecutable_file_formats))

I'm looking for a tool that can recognize what compression tools were used to compress the executable.

For example: say an executable was compressed with UPX: The Ultimate Packer For executables but I had no idea this compressor was used. Can I somehow determine that compressor was used to compress it through the use of a tool?

If you have any recommendations or can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated! I would like to find a tool that can detect various compressors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A start is: try to compress it with something like gzip.  Something already compressed will not compress much, or at all, or perhaps expand a smidge.  If the executable compresses a fair bit, then it was not compressed in the first place.  A quick check shows that most of my executables compress by a factor of almost two.

Then at least you'll know whether or not it's compressed.

From there, you can try compressing executables using [the candidates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_compression), and look for common sequences in the prefix executable, which is the decompressor.

Answer (score 0):

On Unix, use the `file` command.  It tries to determine what kind of data is in a file by matching it against various signatures. It's not specific to executables or compression, those are just some of the kinds of files it can recognize.

Comment: A compressed executable will still look like an executable, since you'll be looking at the decompression code executable at the beginning.  So, no, this won't work.